# Process php : Scanimage -L (usb)

Tags: php, process, usb, scanning

I created a process in my project PHP for display all devices with a scanimage command line, but the output of the process is empty not in a terminal:

- Result in terminal :
  scanimage -L | grep -v "ip="
  *device `fujitsu:fi-6130dj:105613' is a FUJITSU fi-6130dj scanner*
- IResult in process php
  String(0)""

And since grep I have:

- Result in terminal:
  *scanimage -L
  device `fujitsu:fi-6130dj:105613' is a FUJITSU fi-6130dj scanner
  device`hpaio:/net/HP_LaserJet_400_colorMFP_M475dw?ip=192.168.121.121' is a Hewlett-Packard HP_LaserJet_400_colorMFP_M475dw all-in-one*
- Result in process:
  device `hpaio:/net/HP_LaserJet_400_colorMFP_M475dw?ip=192.168.121.121' is a Hewlett-Packard HP_LaserJet_400_colorMFP_M475dw all-in-one*

The problem is just for USB devices.

Answer (score 0):

sudo visudo (and add www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/scanimage )

it's work.